# Change background image in PHP

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a post with the featured image. On my homepage, I want to display the featured image and the post title. But, in media screen < 576px , I want to display only the post title and "NO" featured image. Please see my code below (example) :

```
<div style="background-image:ulr('<?php the_posts_thumbnail_url(); ?>')" class="myPost">
         //some code here
 </div>
```

This code above work fine. I just want to ask how to delete background image in media screen < 576px.

Thanks for your anwsers.

Comment: This is not a WordPress question, it's a CSS question. Please use the correct Stack Exchange website in future - https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Sorry, next time I will be more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to delete the image per se, but using CSS you can hide the image. You should also make sure you fix the typo inside of your inline style it should read `background-image: url(...)`.

For the varying styles, you can utilize media queries to hide at a certain point. I don't recommend using `!important` but it will be the only way to override this inline style using CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
  .myPost{
    background-image: none !important;
  }
}
```